# Javascript loads but doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour on one of my websites. Please take a look to this page.

http://www.piazzaimpianti.it/motori-elettrici

(I suggest you to refresh the page many times, and sometimes you will see the app drawer icon appearing, and sometimes not).

The Javascript functions are loading correctly, but sometimes the left app drawer icon is not showing up, and when it occurs, also the dropdown menu on "Servizi" does not appear.

I tried to modify loading order, putting JS at the beginning and at the end, but JS loads everytime. Sometime happens that it doesn't work.

In particular, the JS fills the divs:

```
<!-- START NAVBAR -->
<header class="mdl-layout__header"></header>
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer"></div>
<div class="mdl-layout-custom__dropdown"></div>
<!-- END NAVBAR -->
```

```js
function createHeaderandFooter() {
  $(function() {
    $(".mdl-layout__header").load("lib/header1.html");
    $(".mdl-layout__drawer").load("lib/header2.html");
    $(".mdl-layout-custom__dropdown").load("lib/header3.html");
    $("#footer").load("lib/footer.html");
  });
}
```

with the content of three different files, then the material design JS implements the functionalities (app drawer on the left and dropdown menu on "Servizi").

Could you please help me to identify the problem?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console when it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I refreshed 50 times, I cannot reproduce what you said

Comment: Sounds like a race condition: sometimes the material design script runs before the the content loads (bad), sometimes it runs after (good). Right now it’s down to luck. You should deliberately run the material design script after the content is ready.

Comment: Cannot reporoduce error

Comment: To do some testing you could delay ui element loading with: setTimeout(function() { loader }, 4000); if it will work each time, you should force script loading order (i see that there is "defer" for material script.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your responses. It is happening on chrome I think... either on desktop and mobile. No errors in the console. I'll try to delay. UPDATE: it's happening also on Firefox

Comment: It seems that the problem is the fact that I'm loading header from files. In fact if I paste it into the main page it is working every time...